# Show the pairing $X\times Map(X,Y)\rightarrow Y$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, let $Map(X,Y)$ be the spaces of all continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$, equipped with compact-open topology.

Is the pairing $X\times Map(X,Y)\rightarrow Y, \ (x,\phi)\mapsto \phi(x)$ continuous? If it is, how to show this?

THANKS A LOT!

Comment: If you take $Y = [0, 1]$ and $X$ be any Tychonoff space that isn't locally compact, then your map isn't continuous.

Comment: Thus, at least for Tychonoff spaces, we have that $(x, \varphi)\mapsto \varphi(x)$ is continuous iff $X$ is locally compact.

Comment: You should consult a textbook on general topology (function spaces, evaluation map).